Applied for French citizenship but am getting a divorce
My French husband and I (a US citizen) got married in USA, have lived in USA and are still in USA. After 5 years of marriage, I applied for French citizenship par declaration, went through the language test and we as a married couple did an interview together at the consulate 4 months ago. My dossier was sent to France and is still pending. Meanwhile, things changed drastically in our relationship, my husband moved out last week and I am about to file for divorce. Question: Did I lose my right to get  French citizenship?

IIUC, you lose the right to become French if and only if the end of your "communauté de vie" with your husband precedes the "souscription" of the declaration. It seems that this should've happened before the dossier was sent to France, but you would know better than I. (I believe "souscription" corresponds roughly to "execution" in US law, i.e. that you formally sign the document; did you do this at the interview?) I am not posting an answer because we have a couple of French regulars who may know the answer or at least will understand the description of the procedure better than I.


Question: Did I lose my right to get French citizenship?

In principle, as @phoog explained, the date that matters is the date you submitted your déclaration. Usually that would be the day you completed your interview and submitted all the documents required. You should have received a récépissé confirming that. The déclaration is not valid until it's been “recorded” by the consulate but once it is, you will be considered to have been French from the date of submission and not the date it was processed nor the date it was notified. If you were still actually living together at the date of submission, you were entitled to French citizenship and haven't done anything wrong.
Importantly, the relevant criteria is called “communauté de vie”, which means something like genuinely living together as a married couple. I understand that it is not the case for you but if your husband had already left your home by the time you submitted your déclaration, you would not be entitled to French citizenship, even if you are still technically married. In theory, that “communauté de vie” must also have been uninterrupted for the last 4 years (5 when living abroad) but courts have been a bit lenient with that.
Where things become a little touchy is that if you separate within one year of becoming French, the state can assume that your application was fraudulent and it will be up to you to prove that you really did live together and did not marry with the intention of fraudulently becoming French.
Here again, what matters is the “communauté de vie”, not the divorce, but I imagine that if you can delay filing for divorce until the end of 2025 (not necessarily a great idea for other reasons, I reckon it's a difficult balancing act), the state is less likely to dispute your déclaration and it might be much easier from a purely procedural point of view. The date that matters here is the date of enregistrement (“recording”), not the date of submission so it could be up to a year and two months from now.
In short, as long as it happens after submitting the déclaration, separating does not automatically mean that you have lost your right to get French citizenship but you might have to fight for it in court.
